# RPC with protocol buffers

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, rpc

I'm tring to make rpc with protocol buffers and zeromq. Here is my proto file:

```
message SearchRequest {
  required string query = 1;
}

message SearchResponse {
  repeated Result result = 1;
}

message Result {
  required string url = 1;
  optional string title = 2;
  repeated string snippets = 3;
}

service SearchService {
  rpc Search (SearchRequest) returns (SearchResponse);
}
```

According to the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#services) I should get some service interface code and stubs for this rpc but I don't. Did I misunderstand something or am I doing it wrong?

I generate sources with `$ protoc test.proto --cpp_out=gen-cpp` and get `test.ph.cc/h` without `SearchService` in content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not do it on my own but it seems like your file is missing an option like `option cc_generic_services = true;` 
Look at the [manual](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#service)